# Ferrite bead in series with buck inductor

Tags: power-electronics, buck, emi-filtering, ferrite-bead

### Background

When filtering DM noise from SMPS, I have often used LC filters in the past. One thing that happens with regular inductors though, is that very high frequency (>100 MHz) switch noise gets through because it couples through the parasitic capacitance of the inductor and is not shunted away because of the parasitic inductance of the capacitor. So one might even form accidental resonances there. Adding a ferrite bead in series with the inductor was a very good way to prevent this and basically extend the filtering capabilities of the inductor to much higher frequencies.

Now I want to make a synchronous buck. I have never seen this approach in any synchronous buck schematic so far. Is it just not necessary because the output noise requirements of most buck converters are rather relaxed?

My target spec is 10 A at a switching frequency of about 1-2 MHz (using GaN), so I expect quite a lot of DM noise at 100 MHz and above.

### Question

Does something like the below schematic make sense if I want to keep switching noise away from the output as well as possible? Obivously, the ferrite bead will help in this regard, but does it have adverse side effects that I don't see?

My thinking is to place it "after" the inductor. That way, the switch node `SW` is kept small and the bead will be at a rather fixed CM potential at node `A` held by `C1`.

Do you think another place might be better suited for the bead?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3K1TN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[This](https://www.laird.com/products/inductive-components-emc-components-and-ferrite-cores/ferrite-beads-on-wire/28f-series/28f0121-0sr-10) is a potential bead I consider to use and this is the impedance from its datasheet:

[image]

Comment: It seems sensible to me to use a FB as you show.

Comment: Makes sense. One thing I see is that the load and the ripple current will flow through it. So the losses might be relatively higher. Since your first aim is to keep the noise away from the load, you can place FB (or a FB-C network with a very small C) between the output cap and the load, for lower losses.

Comment: @RohatKılıç there is even a second LC filter after the output capacitor in the above schematic (I included it now in the schematic). The second LC has barely any ripple current left, so the bead could be placed there. But I thought it is better to place the bead in the first LC section, because otherwise the HF noise will still be present over the `C1` capacitor bank (node `A` is a several cm large node) and I am afraid that that would radiate a lot.

Comment: A ferrite bead is there to severely reduce the di/dt in a branch and avoid a sharp spike during a transition. Here, the bead would permanently endure a dc bias and it would defeat its purpose. The bead, if necessary, should be placed in series with a switching semiconductor like the low-side FET in your circuit, but if you use GaNs, you should not suffer reverse-recovery losses as with the body diode of a MOSFET.

Comment: @VerbalKint I don't know. Inserting a bead into the hot loop of a buck doesn't sound like a good plan to me, but I never thought about it. So you would put it in series with the input capacitance essentially? I will simulate it.. OK: I checked. I get bounces on the input voltage rail of several 10s of Volts.. Doesn't sound good. It will radiate like hell from the large input node. If I place it in series with the FETs, the same will appear on the switch node.

Comment: No, not with the input cap. But, for instance, beads are very common in narrow-spike loops like the RCD network in a flyback converter or in the output diode for damping the ringing. I am not sure simulation will lead to anything interesting as the saturation characteristic of the bead is what matters to see its effect. There are some useful info in this [paper](https://resources.altium.com/sites/default/files/2022-05/Guide%20to%20Using%20Ferrite%20Beads%20in%20a%20PCB.pdf).

Comment: It seems to be a common practice to place a bead between the choke and the output cap, as I see from some app notes. In my previous designs (buck, PFC and LLC) I put in series with one of the switch(es), when needed. I also remember putting one in series with the bootstrap supply input (between the diode-cap junction and the bootstrap pin). This may decrease the slew rate of the switching node, so the output cap will see less ringing, but may not be applicable for a HF switching design such as yours.

Comment: @VerbalKint Ah I see. Yes I have never used beads at such current levels before. I am making sure to model saturation as well. That is also why I insist on a bead with specced current dependence.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Could you link one of these app notes ? As I mentioned above, I haven't seen this mentioned before and would be interested in what an appnote would have to say about it. (Maybe as an answer for its general relevance)

Comment: [This one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62913.pdf) mentions but apparently I misunderstood, sorry (my English {facepalm}). It suggests what I told in my first comment. Sorry again, for the misunderstanding and possible confusion. You may also want to think about compensation for bead's presence as it'll appear in the transfer function.

Comment: Putting FB in series with the switching inductor just seems to be inviting extra heating, and nonlinearity (notice its effect depends on how close a given switching edge is to zero bias). Using an FB in the first place seems rather bulky compared to an inductor proper, like if you want 6 ohms @ 100MHz why not use a 10nH (SMD spring type?) instead, then add whatever damping resistance you need?  Maybe the layout area ends up the same or more in that case, I don't know.

Comment: @TimWilliams have you done the calculations? For a few nH loop inductance to the output caps (through the choke) and a generous 20 pF inductor parallel capacitance, you need several (if not even 10s) ohms for damping, which is prohibitive at 10 A. The bead ***is*** that damping resistor. Its inductance is irrelevant.

Comment: @tobalt Just taking the ballpark figure of the suggested component -- 6 ohms at 100MHz under 8A bias. If this is the minimum you expect from the FB and it is enough for the purpose, then the component is acceptable. It also seems to have a modest Q in that condition (more than 1, anyway; but, reading Q from a |Z| plot is crude at best), and is mostly lossy (Q ~ 1?) only at low bias or closer to resonance -- maybe this is enough damping resistance anyway, maybe not.